# Which event will work in ngx-intl-tel-input in angular?

Tags: angular6, keypress

I'm trying to call a function on keypress but it does not work. Which event will work in `ngx-intl-tel-input`?

```
     <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'custom'" [preferredCountries]="[ 'us','in']" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
         [enablePlaceholder]="true" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" (click)="emailOrPhone()"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ngModelChange` event will work on `ngx-intl-tel-input`.

Used like Inside component html :-

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'custom'" 
                  [preferredCountries]="[ 'us','in']" 
                  [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
                  [enablePlaceholder]="true" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" 
                  (ngModelChange)="checkNumber()">
</ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Inside component TS :-

```
checkNumber(){
  if(this.phoneNumber != null){
    let Data:any = this.phoneNumber;
    console.log("Number :- ",Data.number);
    console.log("Code :- ",Data.internationalNumber);
    console.log("dialCode :- ",Data.dialCode);
  }
 }
```